# How do I multiply two dynamic matrices in C?

Tags: c

I'm trying to multiply two dynamic matrices by passing them through a function. I'm getting a segmentation fault during the multiplication.

The matrices are being passed through a function. The items in the arguments are correct because I had to use them for a different operation in this project. I have a feeling that I messed up with the pointers, but i'm pretty new to C and i'm not sure where I messed up.

```
double** multiplyMatrices(
    double** a,
    const uint32_t a_rows,
    const uint32_t a_cols,
    double** b,
    const uint32_t b_cols){

    uint32_t i = 0;
    uint32_t j = 0;
    uint32_t k = 0;
    double** c;

//allocate memory to matrix c
    c = (double **)malloc(sizeof(double *) * a_rows);
    for (i = 0; i < a_rows; i++) {
        *(c +i) = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * b_cols);
     }

//clear matrix c
    for(i = 0; i < a_rows; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < a_cols; j++){
            *c[j] = 0;
       }
    }

    i = 0;

//multiplication
    while(j = 0, i < a_rows ){
        while(k = 0, j < b_cols){
            while(k < a_cols){
                //following line is where i'm getting the segmentation fault
                *(*(c+(i*b_cols))+j) += (*(*(a+(i*a_cols))+k)) * (*(*(b+(k*b_cols))+j));
                k++;
            }
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return c;
}
```

Comment: There also seems to be an error with how you clear matrix c (Apart from the fact that it is not necessary). The variable i from the outer loop is not used inside the loop at all, so all you are doing is repeating the inner loop an additional a_rows times. It is also not necessary to do this manually, you can use `calloc()` instead of malloc. Its parameters work a little different but the result is exactly the same. If you want to all-zero any area of memory you can also use `bzero()` or `memset()`.

Comment: Even though it doesn't throw an error, code to clear the 'c' matrix is wrong. `*c[j]` will refer to the exact same set of values in every iteration of outer for loop.
Use better methods like @ThomasLeyk have suggested. 

Still if you want to go with bare approach, use it like `c[i][j] = 0` or `c[i*a_rows + j ] = 0`.

Answer (score 3):

The obvious mistake is that you dereference `c + i * b_cols` while c is an array of pointers of size `a_rows`. So likely `c + i * b_cols` is outside of the area that you previously allocated with `malloc()`.

I would suggest to simplify the matrix representation using a single array of `double` with the size equal to the total number of elements, i.e. rows * cols.

For example:

```
double *c;

c = malloc(sizeof(double) * a_rows * b_cols);
```

This not only has better overall performance, but simplifies the code. You would then have to "linearise" the offset inside your unidimensional array to convert from bi-dimensional matrix coordinates. For example:

```
c[i * b_cols + j] = ...
```

Of course, the other two matrices need to be allocated, filled and accessed in a similar manner.

For code clarity, I would also replace the `while` statements by `for` statements with the actual variable that they loop on. For example:

```
for (i = 0; i < a_rows; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < b_cols; j++)
       for (k = 0; k < a_cols; k++)
```

You can (ab)use the C language in many ways, but the trick is to make it more clear for you in the first place.